# Using vectors, conds and structs

Tags: vector, struct, racket

I'm creating a struct which will show a list of floors in a hotel (e.g. floor 1, floor 2) and the number of rooms which are empty on each floor. I have created a vector which allows the user to edit if a room is "empty" or "full". The only problem I have is I can't work out how to create code which shows the number of rooms free in each floor that I can enter into my struct. I'm guessing using a cond will work but I really don't know how to write it.

This is what I've done so far:

```
#lang racket
(define floor-one (make-vector 10))

(vector-set! floor-one 0 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-one 1 "full")
(vector-set! floor-one 2 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-one 3 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-one 4 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-one 5 "full")
(vector-set! floor-one 6 "full")
(vector-set! floor-one 7 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-one 8 "full")
(vector-set! floor-one 9 "full")

(define floor-two (make-vector 10))

(vector-set! floor-two 0 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-two 1 "full")
(vector-set! floor-two 2 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-two 3 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-two 4 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-two 5 "full")
(vector-set! floor-two 6 "full")
(vector-set! floor-two 7 "empty")
(vector-set! floor-two 8 "full")
(vector-set! floor-two 9 "full")

(struct hotel-rooms (floor rooms-empty)) 


(define empty-rooms1 (λ (any->vector x)
                   (cond
                     ())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a perfect function for the task: [`vector-count`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-count%29%29). Try this:

```
(define empty-rooms
  (λ (vec)
    (vector-count (λ (floor) (string=? floor "empty"))
                  vec)))
```

Or even simpler:

```
(define (empty-rooms vec)
  (vector-count (curry string=? "empty") vec))
```

For example:

```
(empty-rooms floor-one)
=> 5
```